# Is it possible to specify what I want to auto increment?

Tags: excel, auto-increment, vba

I have a cell with the format "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss". I want to auto increment the minute, but when I manually auto increment after selecting only that cell, it increments the *day.* To make it increment the minute, I have to manually copy the cell below, add one minute, select both and THEN increment. Is it possible to, in VBA, specify what part of the cell I want to be incremented when I use the

```
Selection.AutoFill
```

function and only have one cell selected? As it is, recording the macro gives me

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BU2:BU3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: No. [Range.AutoFill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx) only takes 2 parameters. To Autofill the way you want, you'll need to have at least 2 source cells to establish a pattern.

Comment: It sounds like you've solved your own problem - selecting two cells allows Excel to determine the increment interval.

Comment: Doing everything I did by hand programmatically is possible, but I was hoping there was as simpler way of doing it. But thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel dates and times are stored differently then in other languages.

From http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm

> Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of
>   days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day: 
>   ddddd.tttttt
>
> This is called a serial date, or serial date-time.

If you want to increment by minute then you should add the fraction of a day that is equal to one minute

```
Minutes in a day = 1440

1 / 1440 = 0.00069444
```

Set your auto increment function to **0.00069444** and it should work they way you expect.